# Certificação Digital A3

Tags: java, java-ee

Recentemente fui engajado para o desenvolvimento de uma aplicação que deve utilizar `Certificação Digital A3` utilizando um `token`. Não tenho nenhuma experiência com certificações digitais e queria saber como iniciar com certificações digitais tipo o passo a passo ou um norte pois estou perdido kk, e como conseguir pegar o certificado do `token`.

Fico muito grato desde já.

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOpt. Cara, tua pergunta é muito ampla, apesar de válida. Você já consegue algo, como trabalhar com certiricados A1, apenas não consegue recuperar as chaves do A3? Tenta criar pequenas perguntas específicas.

Comment: Nunca trabalhei com certificação digital, e não tenho noção como trabalhar com certificação digital A3, estou pesquisando bastante ainda já estou vendo algumas alternativa. Gostaria de saber como trabalhar com certificação A3. Fico Grato.